# Error Mysql "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Tags: mysql, count

i have an error in mysql i activate you guys help me i have followed stack overflow with topic i still have the same error

```
                              SELECT
                              (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                FROM(SELECT DISTINCT status from absen_sore where nip='198606102011011005' AND opd='Dinas Komunikasi Dan Informatika' AND  MONTH(waktu) ='05')as dt)+
                                (
                                SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                FROM(SELECT DISTINCT status from ijin where nip='198606102011011005' AND opd='Dinas Komunikasi Dan Informatika' AND  MONTH(waktu) ='05' AND status='Konfirmasi'))as dt
```

Comment: Some closing parenthesis are lost...

Comment: can you write the correct query in the column I've tried it